# Disable event logs for network connections

Tags: java, blackberry, event-log

In the eventlogger, if i change the Min log level to "Debug info" and do some network calls, I have noticed that the connection factory logs the network url .For example , I saw this

guid:0x287F0A38583E7BC6 time: Mon Jan 21 18:29:15 2013  severity:5 type:2 app:net.rim.networkapi data:FcoC https://xyz.co.uk/abc/test?appversion=1.2.3&;deviceside=false;ConnectionType=mds-public;ConnectionTimeout=20000;EndToEndRequired

This happens for all the apps I work for. Is there any way we could do something to avoid the connectionfactory from logging this information in the event logger

Comment: I don't think so. Check your connection classes, maybe a log call has sneaked there somehow :)

Comment: @MisterSmith this happens with not just our apps but other apps as well. the following log was posted in support forums by another user d net.rim.networkapi - FcoC https://xyz.com:8443/services/rest/ProfileService/Profile/;deviceside=true;ConnectionUID=WAP2 trans - 3/30 09:59:21 . So it looks like if we use the connection factory, it logs every time a connection is created

Comment: I've been able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @MisterSmith RIM have confirmed that there is no way for an application to prevent being logged in the event log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were right, the full URL is logged with severity 5 (`EventLogger.DEBUG_INFO`) by the app `net.rim.networkapi data`. Sometimes, when using Wi-Fi or direct TCP, the URL is even logged twice. This can be a security problem as hosts and querystrings are logged.

Changing the severity level to `EventLogger.INFORMATION` seems to prevent the undesired logging.

Sample app (manually clean event logger first):

```
    public class Main extends Application{

        public Main(){
            doTest();
        }

        private void doTest(){
            long GUID = 0x9cf1bac07b565732L; 
            EventLogger.register(GUID, "conn_factory_logging_test", EventLogger.VIEWER_STRING);
            EventLogger.setMinimumLevel(EventLogger.INFORMATION);

            ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
            factory.setPreferredTransportTypes(new int[]{ TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_WIFI, TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_CELLULAR});
            ConnectionDescriptor cd = factory.getConnection("http://www.google.com");
            HttpConnection httpConnection = (HttpConnection) cd.getConnection();
            try {
                httpConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
                int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
                String result = "Server Response: " + responseCode;

                EventLogger.logEvent(GUID, result.getBytes(), EventLogger.INFORMATION);
                EventLogger.startEventLogViewer();          
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            } finally {
                try {
                    httpConnection.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {}
            }       
            System.exit(0);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
             new Main().enterEventDispatcher();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are the man. Awesome. this works !!! Unfortunately I could only vote once. !!! :-)

Comment: You are welcome. Seems to work, but I could not test it thoroughly so let's hope this gets rid of ninja logging. I was not aware of this issue, but thanks to you I've also modified one of my biggest projects.

Comment: The suggestion from RIM is to avoid GET and send sensitive data using POST

Comment: @rfsk2010 yeah, that's common practice in the web development world. But even using post, I'd like to hide as much as possible which servers and ports I'm connecting to.